# How to bind a variable within a list in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have an unknown list of variables that I wish to bind to specific controls within a WPF application.  Is there a way to bind a variable out of the list with a specific name?

Here is a code example of what I am trying to do.

C#

```
public class Variable {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class VariableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    Variable _variable;
    public Variable Variable {
        get {
            return(_variable);
        }
        set {
            _variable = value;
            if(PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Variable"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class VariableListViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<VariableViewModel> VariableList { get; set; }

    public VariableListViewModel() {
        VariableList = new ObservableCollection<VariableViewModel>();
        var variableViewModel = new VariableViewModel { 
            Variable = new Variable { Name = "my_variable_name" } 
        };
        VariableList.Add(variableViewModel);
    }
}
```

WPF:

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VariableListViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name, ElementName=my_variable_name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The label is clearly wrong here.  My question is whether or not what I am trying to achieve is possible?  I want to be able to display 'my_variable_name'.

-Stuart

Comment: I know I could write a converter for this.  Or, since I know which variable name I want to display before-hand, I could also hardcode a variable named 'my_variable_name' and then bind to that directly.  I want to know if it is possible to do this dynamically with an unknown list of variables, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) (or other `ItemsControl`), and bind its `ItemsSource` to your collection (`VariableList`).

This will cause each item (a `VariableViewModel`) to get displayed.  You'd then use a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) to cause the `VariableViewModel` to display as a Label bound to `Variable.Name`.

Comment: I wanted to display only a specific variable from the list, so an ItemsControl wouldn't work in this scenario.

Comment: @Stuart You could still use a DataTemplate, and just bind to `VariableList[0]` (or whatever index you'd like).

Comment: How would I bind to VariableList[0]?  When I try adding ItemsSource="{Binding VariableList[0]}", it shows up blank.

Comment: @Stuart `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=VariableList[0]}" />`

Comment: That's cool.  Is there a way to do that without knowing the index within the list?  I.e. Path=(from VariableList where Variable.Name == my_variable_name select Variable.Name)

Comment: @Stuart No - you'd have to handle that in your `ViewModel`, as it requires a fair amount of "logic" - you could do a converter, but I'd put that in the VM directly.

Comment: @Stuart Another option I just thought of - you could have a data template that was "collapsed" when it wasn't the matching item, and then handle this via a ListView - all of your non-matches would be hidden, then.

Comment: That's perfect!  I'll post my final result below just in case someone else needs a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ValueConverter` and use its ConverterParameter to pass in the name of the variable:

```
public object ConvertTo(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var variableList = (IEnumerable<Variable>)value;
    var variableName = parameter != null ? parameter.ToString() : string.Empty;
    return variableList.FirstOrDefault(v=>v.Name == variableName);
}
```

You could then use that converter in XAML as follows:`

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ListOfVariables, 
                         Converter={StaticResource VariableConverter}, 
                         ConverterParameter='VariableName'}" />
```

Comment: I'm in the process of learning MVVM, so I'm trying to avoid using converters if I can help it.  This approach would work, however.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contradicts itself.

On the one hand you say you have an unknown list of variables, on the other hand your View knows which variables it wants to bind to.

So, either you know which variables you want to bind to or you don't know it.

### Scenario 1: You know which variables you want to bind to:

Create a property per Variable in your ViewModel

### Scenario 2: You don't know which variables you want to bind to:

Bind your `VariableList` property to an `ItemsControl` in the View and provide a `DataTemplate` that can render a `VariableViewModel`.

---

BTW: Having a `VariableViewModel` seems to be superfluous. You could use `Variable` directly. Especially when all `VariableViewModel` does is returning the `Variable` inside.

Comment: I'll probably end up using Scenario 1.  I was trying to avoid having to copy data from a list (generated from a text file of variables given from a client) into a specific variable.  The variable will be displayed in several locations as well as in list format.  Also, thanks for the tip on the VariableViewModel.  I'm just getting into MVVM, so I'm learning as I go here.

Comment: I'm going to be using Scenario 1 as you mentioned.  I'm marking Reed's answer as correct, however, since it answers my question more directly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Reeds solution and comments, here is my final solution.  I used the same model and view model, so I will only show the View.

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VariableListViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemsControlDataTemplate">
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Variable.Name}">
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="my_variable_name">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsControlDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VariableList}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```